# protecting php email form

Tags: php, html, email

I would like to know if what I have done would stop injection on my email form.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "ask@mywebsite.co.uk"; 
    $from = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank-you I thought it seemed far too easy to do.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "injection"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

headers are the only injection point, and you only have one variable to take care of **$from** and you do that  with `filter_var`

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing you can do to stop injection attacks is to properly escape content for its target context.

You've already done that by filtering the from email address, which *in this case* is sufficient to protected the email address from causing problems. In general, though, filtering is not sufficient to prevent injection attacks.

You also hard-code your subject, which is good. The documentation for [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) requires that the subject must satisfy [RFC 2047](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html), which is probably more reading than anyone actually wants to do. For these types of forms, it's probably best to use a subject that's defined in your code so that you can avoid any surprises, so you're covered there.

In general, you want to make sure the subject, and *especially* any headers that you add to the email, *do not* contain unexpected newlines, since that is the primary attack vector for `mail()`. Since your headers consist only of a sanitized and static email address, you should be good there as well.

Comment: his subject is hard codded

Comment: @Dagon Updated. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!